# Build failed for new configuration, old configuration is working (C# Window application)

Tags: tfs

We have one build definition which is successfully working.
But now we have added new configuration in project ,so for that we have created new build definition same as old one.

when we queue the new build following error getting,

Exception Message: Sequence contains no elements (type InvalidOperationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the configuration added to both the solution and the project? Assuming that you build the solution rather than the project.

Comment: @ Tore Østergaard -Yes,solution

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using old XAML build or new build system? Which configuration did you add? Could you provide detailed steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Also, try to use MSBuild command line to build the solution manually on the build agent machine, and check the result.

Comment: Could you please share steps to build from msbuild command line